# Hibernate: how to prevent entity creation?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a type of entity that must not be created or updated by application, .e.g. `Country` entity. Its corresponding table is filled manually, the application must only read from it.

I'm using the `@Immutable` to mark that the entity must not be changed. But I can not find an analog annotation to prevent entity creation. Are there possibilities from Hibernate to prevent an application from creating an entity?

Comment: you could ... not provide code to create them, I assume?

Comment: yes, but I was thinking of some solution like `@Immutable`, that explicitly marks the entity

Comment: This seems like it would be better _enforced_ by the DBMS, if possible. Then in the Java code, simply don't write code to insert/update/delete `Country` entities. Though perhaps you could throw an exception from an `@PrePersist` handler? I don't know what the defined behavior is in that case, however.

Comment: How about making it impossible to insert into the entity table by e.g. not configuring the id generation i.e. remove `@GeneratedValue`?